# Connect GWT Application to Oracle DB brings 'invalid username/password; logon denied' - Login works with QuantumDB?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, gwt

I have a GWT Application running local on my Computer via SuperDevMode with integrated Jetty. The Application works fine, but I need to connect to a Oracle DB.
I did th following:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws ConfigurationException {
    try {
      if (conn == null) {
        createConnection();
      }
      return conn;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println();
      throw new ConfigurationException(e);
    }
  }

  private static void createConnection() throws ConfigurationException, SQLException {
    try {
      String url = ConfigHelper.getJdbcUrl();
      String user = ConfigHelper.getJdbcUser();
      String password = ConfigHelper.getJdbcPassword();
      String schema = ConfigHelper.getJdbcSchema();
      String driverName = ConfigHelper.getJdbcDriver();
      Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

      DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      conn.setSchema(schema);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw new ConfigurationException(e);
    }
  }
```

I try to create the connection; I have a helper class "ConfigHelper" which reads a config file with all the Information. 
When I start the Application in DebugMode I can see I get the right values from the config file.
However I get this Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at de.axa.schadenreserveOnline.server.db.DBHelper.createConnection(DBHelper.java:51)
at de.axa.schadenreserveOnline.server.db.DBHelper.getConnection(DBHelper.java:32)
... 73 more
```

The strange thing is, if I use the QuantumDB Plugin for Eclipse to connect to the same Oracle DB with the same data from my config file it works.

Is there anything I missed creating the connection?
I apreciate any help
Thanks in Advance

Edit:
using ojdbc6 11.2.0.3
GWT 2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You have a default case sensitive username and password in the database.
Many applications are automatically converted  username and password to uppercase.
It is necessary to type the username and password correctly in the case sensitive 
or change the parameter of the authentication of Oracle

**sec_case_sensitive_logon=false.**

test parameter **sec_case_sensitive_logon=false.**

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> show parameter sec_case

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------------------------
sec_case_sensitive_logon             boolean     TRUE
```

change  parameter **sec_case_sensitive_logon=false.** (you need right dba)

```
SQL> alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=false scope=both;

System altered.

SQL> show parameter sec_case

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------------------------
sec_case_sensitive_logon             boolean     FALSE
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was no Error whatsoever, only a little Problem form my side:
In my Config file the Password for the DB was correct, but it contained a '\' 
- I needed to escape this with '\'